# Add background color to cells, reportlab python

Tags: python, reportlab

```
    summary = [['Metrics','Status']]
    try:
        for i in output['responsetimes']:
            if  i['metric'] == 'ResponseTime':
                k = i['value'].split(' ')
                if int(k[0])<1000:
                    temp = ['Response Times','Green']
                    summary.append(temp)
                else:
                    temp = ['Response Times','Red']
                    summary.append(temp)                    
    except:
        summary.append(['Response Times','NA'])

    try:                    
        for i in output['runtimedumps']:
            if i['metric'] == 'Shortdumps Frequency':
                k = i['value'].split(' ')
                if int(k[0])==0:
                    temp = ['Runtime Dumps','Green']
                    summary.append(temp)
                else:
                    temp = ['Runtime Dumps','Red']
                    summary.append(temp)
    except:
        summary.append(['Runtime Dumps','NA']) 

    try:                   
        temp = []            
        for i in output['buffer']:
            
            if (i['metric'] == 'HitRatio'):
                k = i['value'].split(' ')
                if int(k[0])>95:
                     temp.append('green')
                else:
                    temp.append('red')
        if 'red' in temp:
            summary.append(['Buffer','Red'])
        else:
            summary.append(['Buffer','Green'])                
    except:
        summary.append(['Buffer','NA'])

    try:            
        for i in output['updatemonitoring']:
            if i['metric'] == 'ErrorsInWpUD1':
                if int(i['value'])==0:
                    temp = ['Update Monitoring','Green']
                    summary.append(temp)
                else:
                    temp = ['Update Monitoring','Red']
                    summary.append(temp)                              
    except:
        summary.append(['Update Monitoring','NA'])                              

    try:
        for i in output['memory']:
            if i['metric'] == 'Physical':
                total = int(i['value'].split(' ')[0])
            if i['metric'] == 'Free (Value)':
                free = int(i['value'].split(' ')[0])
        if int((free*100)/total)<5:
           summary.append(['Memory Utilization','Red'])
        else:
            summary.append(['Memory Utilization','Green'])        
    except:
        summary.append(['Memory Utilization','Green'])        

    try:            
        for i in output['cpu']:
            if i['metric'] == 'CPU_Utilization':
                used = int(i['value'].split(' ')[0])
        if used>80:
            summary.append(['CPU Utilization','Red'])
        else:
            summary.append(['CPU Utilization','Green'])                    
    except:
        summary.append(['CPU Utilization','NA'])                            

    try:    
        temp = []            
        for i in output['fs']:
            if int(i['perc'].split(' ')[0])>85:
                temp.append('red')
            else:
                temp.append('green')            

        if 'red' in temp:
            summary.append(['File System','Red'])
        else:
            summary.append(['File System','Green'])
    except:
        summary.append(['File System','NA'])
    
    t=Table(summary,hAlign='LEFT')
    GRID_STYLE = TableStyle(
        [

            ('GRID',(0,0),(-1,-1),0.5,colors.black),
            ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), '#2766A8'),
            ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.white),

        ]
    )
    t.setStyle(GRID_STYLE)
    Story.append(t)  
    Story.append(Spacer(1, 12))
```

I am creating a table using report lab,
You can see how it looks in the image below:
[image: Table illustration]
I want to highlight the cell based on their values.
For example, `Response Times` cell would be green if its value is green or red otherwise.
I'm new at this, and can use some guidance on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer myself after some more searching stackoverflow questions.
Might help someone else..
In my case, list `summary` has the heading by default which is `['Metrics','Status']`
and I'm appending the rest of the values based on validations like this,

```
        for i in output['responsetimes']:
        if  i['metric'] == 'ResponseTime':
            k = i['value'].split(' ')
            if int(k[0])<1000:
                temp = ['Response Times','Green']
                summary.append(temp)
            else:
                temp = ['Response Times','Red']
                summary.append(temp)
```

So in the end my `summary` list looks something like this,

```
[
['Metrics','Status'],
['Response','Green'],
['Metrics2','Red'],
['Metrics4','Green'],
['Metrics3','Red']
]
```

And now I just need to loop over this `summary` list and add styles to the already existing `GRID_STYLE` with the help of `TableStyle` class like this,

```
    GRID_STYLE = TableStyle(
        [

            ('GRID',(0,0),(-1,-1),0.5,colors.black),
            ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), '#2766A8'),
            ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.white),

        ]
    )
    for row, values, in enumerate(summary):
        for column, value in enumerate(values):
            if value == "Red":
                GRID_STYLE.add('BACKGROUND', (column, row), (column, row), colors.red)
            if value == "Green":
                GRID_STYLE.add('BACKGROUND', (column, row), (column, row), colors.green)    

    t.setStyle(GRID_STYLE)
```

And voila, now the table looks like this,
[image]

Comment: It also works to color things if you make an import like this.....from reportlab.lib.colors import *.....and then you could write it simply like this ('GRID',(0,0),(-1,-1),0.5, pink),   and it will work.

Comment: You can click the tick beside your answer to accept it as the answer and you will get points.

Comment: Yes, importing is one way to do it. I just happened to do it this way :).